# Spring Jpa one to many relationship in rest reponse

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

```
Authors     
Author_ID (PK)  Author_name genre_group
1               Peter       G01


Genres      
genre_group genre          Description
G01         Action         Action…………..
G01         Adventure      Adventure………….
G01         Mystery        Mysrie………………..
```

I  have above two tables. I want to achieve response in rest format like below

```
1
Peter
[Action,Adventure,Msytery]
```

can someone tell how should I define my entity classes, mapping and repository to achieve above response?

Answer (score 0):

Idea is create response class for *Authors* and *Genere* entity.

```
class AuthorResponse {
    private long authorId;
    private String authorName;
    private String genres;

}

class GenresResponse {
   private String genre;

  public String toString(){
      return this.genre;
  }
}

public static GenresResponse generResponse(Genre genere) {
        GenresResponse response = new GenresResponse ();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(genere, response);
        return response;
    }

public static AuthorResponse authorResponse(Author author) {
        AuthorResponse response = new AuthorResponse();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(author, response);

        // Not really required to convert. But I suggest to clear separation between
       // entity class and  entity response class
        List<GenerResponse> generes = author.getGenres().stream().
          map(ModelConverter::generResponse)
         .collect(Collectors.toSet()));


       response.setGenre(generes.toString());
        return response;
    }


 PSVM {
   Author author = <get from repository>
   authorResponse(author)
 }
```

Comment: Use https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-mapping-example/ to see one-to-many springJPA example. You can follow my answer once you get _author_ detail from database.